# creating a wcf client instance using unity

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

So currently I'm creating a wcf client instance using the following code:

```
Service1Client client = (Service1Client)_container.Resolve<IService1>(new ParameterOverride("remoteAddress", url),
                    new ParameterOverride("endpointConfigurationName", "basicEndpoint"));
```

however this doesn't work when I'm creating unit tests as I'm casting the object as a Service1Client so my unit test bombs out as it cannot cast a Mock object:

```
 //Mock the WCF service
 var wcfMock = new Mock<IService1>();

 //register with container!
 var container = new UnityContainer();
 container.RegisterInstance(wcfMock.Object);
```

Any ideas on how best to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why are you casting to `Service1Client` ?

Comment: So I can access Open, abort and Close of System.ServiceModel.ClientBase

Comment: Sounds to me you need to write a wrapper around the service-client, which implements an interface, so you can `Mock` it.

Answer (score 1):

You claim to be casting to `Service1Client` so you can access the methods `Open()`, `Abort()` and `Close()` of `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`.

Those methods are defined in [`System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject(v=vs.110).aspx), so let your interface `IService1` inherit from that:

```
public interface IService1 : ICommunicationObject
{
}
```

Then you can omit the cast.